# Set Scene Actuator BGE

Tags: game-engine

I have set scene/ end scene actuators set up to end one level and start the next, it ends the current scene but doesn't bring up the second. Instead the camera views the world background colour as if the camera is not positioned correctly on the second level. When viewing camera view on this level it shows what i would like to see. I am very new to blender and imagine i have missed something really simple. Any help would be amazing!

The first image is of the camera view when playing Game Over scene.
The second is the scene/camera view brought up when the player fails (this should be what is shown in the first image but looks like the camera is zoomed in?.

[image: camer view on game over scene][image: game over view when playing game]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is as you wrote .. the camera has nothing to show. Be aware when switching scene, the active camera will be used (in difference when starting from viewport - if it is not a camera view it creates a new camera ignoring the active one). Unfortunately I can't tell what happens in your scenes.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Screenshots or a [blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Problem solved. I had not set the camera as the 'scene camera' so the scene was not picking up what i wanted. Thanks for enquiring about my problem!